# PermissionError:[error 13] permission denied: scr.png

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, subprocess

hy i make an exe file (coded in pyhon3) that take screenshoot. my exe file is working . Now i add my exe file to startup  using `subprocess.call(r'REG ADD "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /V "takescreenshoot" /t REG_SZ /F  /D "' + location + '"', shell=True`)but when i reboot my pc then on startup i get Error

"“`site-packages\PIL\image.py”,line 2131, in save…PermissionError:[error 13] permission denied: scr.png "`

**Piece of Code is:**

```
snapshot = ImageGrab.grab()

    # Using png because it cannot write mode RGBA as JPEG
    file = "scr.png"
    snapshot.save(file)
```

Comment: Since you just write it into the current working directory. I suspect when you run it at start-up, the `CWD` is somewhere where the process cannot write.

Comment: can you pls explain

Comment: `scr.png` is a relative path, relative to current working directory. When you run your script by hand, the working directory is quite likely different (and one where user under which the script runs can write) to the one when started by Windows itself (also under different user).